# How to write into a file from a different directory, place a name and number into that file and have it sort it and print the updated file

Tags: linux

Write a script that will add a new name and telephone number to the phonebook file you made
in Homework 2, Exercise 2. The new name and number should be accepted as arguments to the
script. The script should sort the phonebook alphabetically after each new name is entered. The
script should print “newName has been entered.” to the screen (replace newName with the
value of the name the user enters as an argument).

This is my code I have so far for it:

```
cat ~/csci323/homework2/exercise2
sort -o ~/csci323/homework2/exercise2

read -p 'Enter name and number to add: ' newName
$newName >> ~/csci323/homework2/exercise2
echo "$newName has been entered"
cat ~/csci323/homework2/exercise2
```

The problem with this code is that when executed it will either exit my turing server or infinitely repeat the name and number that was input.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Sorry, but I don't understand what's your question is or how this bash script relates to vim. Can you clarify what the problem is?

Comment: So the first block of text up top is what im trying to achieve. I have to, from a different directory, write into a file named "exercise2" which contains a list of names and number like a phonebook. It has to allow users to input a name and number and the script will take it and place it into exercise2 and sort it then print the contents of exercise2 back out.

Comment: OK, if your question is "how to do I do this?" can you edit the post to include it? Even then, the question is too broad. Please describe what's wrong with the current code and pick a specific thing to ask about. See [ask] for assistance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add the sorted file to a variable, then add the new name to the variable, sort it again and write it out to a new file rather than append.

Because you won't be able to append the new name to the file without potentialy changing the whole file.

Comment: "Add the sorted file to a variable, then add the new name to the variable" so something like this? upFile = sort -o ~/csci323/homework2/exercise2

Comment: Remember to add the new name to the variable and then sort it again, then write it out

Comment: Im sorry, Ive just started learning how to code and this is all very confusing to me. How would I go about adding the new name to the sorted variable?

Comment: Ok I've added the new name to the variable but now when I execute the code it tells me I dont have permission to write to "exercise2"

Comment: ah it's either locked or you don't have perm. do a ls -lrat on execerise2 to see if you have write perm, is not chmod it. If it's a file locking issue, write it out to exercise3, delete exercise2 and then rename exercise3 to 2